# The usage of another. Is it ok to say another jeans?

Tags: usage

I learned "another" is followed by singular noun. But what about this situation?
I go to the mall to buy jeans, and some sales person recommends some jeans. But I don't like them, and want to see another.
In this situation, is it ok to say " Can I see another jeans?"

Answer (score 2):

You can say 'another' for count nouns but not mass nouns.

You can't say 'a rice' but you can say 'a grain of rice'.

You can't say 'another' jeans,  but you can say 'another *pair of* jeans'.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, but you usually use another 'pair of' jeans. This is to be used generally while referring to any kind of trousers.

Comment: Yes this is also true of other things which are only functional as a pair. For example scissors, tongs and calipers. We can sometimes have a singular modifier derived from the noun as in "A trouser leg", " A scissor action", "a caliper measurement" and so on but if we take the pair apart we can't refer to the half pair by a single noun; we have to talk about "a trouser leg" or "a scissor blade" for instance. This is different from things which are usually paired but have an independent function and existence: we can talk about "a glove" or "a shoe" for example.

Comment: I agree that "another pair of jeans" is better, but you seem to think "another jeans" is OK, yet I don't think it's something a native English speaker (in UK, Commonwealth, or US at least) would say. A fashionista might say "another jean", using the singular sense of "jean". But another + plural is wrong.